# Compactly supported probability measure in high dimensions with fast Fourier decay?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

For any sufficiently large $d\in\mathbb{N}$, does there exist a probability measure $\Psi$ supported on the Euclidean ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$ for which $|\widehat{\Psi}[\omega]|\le C\cdot \exp(-\|\omega\|^{0.99}_2)$ for all $\omega$, or perhaps for all $\omega$ satisfying $\|\omega\|_2 \gtrsim \log(d)$ (here $C$ is any dimension-independent constant)? More modestly, it would even be good to know if there is any such distribution $\Psi$ satisfying super-algebraic decay, perhaps outside of a radius of $d^{o(1)}$.

All this should be possible if one drops the condition that $\Psi$ be nonnegative, as one could take the inverse Radon transform of any smooth, symmetric probability measure over $[-1,1]$ with sufficiently rapid Fourier decay.

Comment: This is a bit inconvenient to unwrap in this form. Couldn't you state directly in terms of $\omega$ what kind of decay you want (rather than in terms of the inverse function)? In other words, you want $|\widehat{\Psi}(\omega)|\lesssim f(|\omega|)$ for what kind of $f$?

Comment: I have edited the wording of the question accordingly.

Comment: This seems to be impossible (unless you have a gaussian) due to the uncertainty principle? See the Hardy's uncertainty principle here (https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/hardys-uncertainty-principle/ or http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2014/REUPapers/Talbut.pdf). In particular, we know that $\| \psi \|_{\infty} < \infty$ since it is supported on a compact set. Then if you want $\hat{\psi}$ to have that decay property, then it satisfies that $\| e^{- \|\omega\|^2 }\hat{\psi}\|_{\infty} < \infty$ so by the thm, $\psi$ has to be a multiple of a gaussian.

Comment: Hi Sandeep, not sure I follow. By that reasoning, there wouldn't exist such a $\Psi$ even for $d = 1$, which is not the case, e.g. if you take $\hat{\Psi}$ to be a suitable infinite product of sinc's. Note that I'm asking for much weaker tails than $\exp(-|\omega|^2)$, which Paley-Wiener would rule out anyways.

Comment: Just to be clear, am I right that your problem is with uniformity of the statement in $d$? Because if $C$ is allowed to depend on $d$ then this is quite easy to achieve starting with $1$-dimensional example and taking its tensor product with itself.

Comment: Hi Aleksei, yes that is right.

Comment: Hm, the power 0.99 is quite hard. If you want 0.49 I think if you take one of the bumps of the [Fabius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function) and define $\Psi$ to be radial having that profile, then it works. (Basically because you have the uniform bound $|(\partial_r)^n f| \lesssim 4^{n^2}$ (not being too careful with my constants here).) The gap between this example and what you want is essentially the gap between $n^2$ and $n\log(n)$.

Comment: @SandeepSilwal: what is being asked for is just slightly outside of what you can rule out using Hardy-type uncertainty principles. Had the OP asked for power 1.01 instead if 0.99, then uncertainty principle would apply.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think one can't get any kind of decay within a radius of order $\sqrt{d}$. First, note that for sufficiently large $d$ and some absolute constant $c>0$, for $0\le z\le c\sqrt{d}$, $\frac{J_{d/2-1}(z)}{z^{d/2-1}}$ is at least $1/2$ times its limit at $z = 0$.

Returning to the question, we may assume wlog that the distribution $\Psi$ over the unit ball is radial, so for $\|x\|_2 = r$, define $\psi(r)\triangleq \Psi(x)$. For some absolute $c>0$ and $d$ sufficiently large, for $\|\omega\|_2 = R \in [0,c\sqrt{d}]$, $$\widehat{\Psi}[\omega] = (2\pi)^{d/2}\int^1_0 \frac{J_{d/2-1}(Rs)}{(Rs)^{d/2-1}}s^{d-1}\psi(s)\ ds \ge \frac{1}{2}\widehat{\Psi}[0] = \frac{1}{2}.$$